# How does ruby find gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have installed a gem called [CSApi](https://github.com/unRob/CouchSurfing-API).
`ruby -e 'require "CSApi"'` runs fine.
`gem env` shows that */Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0* is on my GEM PATH, and there is a file */Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/CSApi-0.0.5/lib/csapi.rb*
I assume this is the file being loaded when i require *CSApi*.

**Main question**: How does ruby find this file? Is the whole directory structure under */Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0* traversed to find a file called *csapi.rb*?

**Side question**: There is also a file */Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/CSApi-0.0.5/examples/example.rb* that was installed as part of the gem. Can this ruby script be invoked without typing the full path?

Comment: I think you might find this artcile useful: http://www.sitepoint.com/rubygems-slow/

Answer (score 1):

You can see the paths require traverses by typing

```
ruby -e 'puts $:'
```

Ok, sorry that was incomplete, this should show the gem paths:

```
ruby -r rubygems -e "p Gem.path"
```

Comment: _/Library/Ruby/Gems_ is not listed, and indeed `ruby -e 'puts $:' | xargs -I{} find {} -iname 'CSApi*'` gives nothing.